# Google Spreadsheets: match multiple variables in multiple columns using match

Tags: google-sheets

Google Spreadsheets: I am trying to match multiple variables in multiple columns

I have tried this code

```
=match(T7&C7&"v";T$2:T6&C$2:C6&K$2:K6)
```

that I expected would woork, but it does not .... any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Can you give a screenshot or example of your data?

Comment: Add new link. Should work. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TPG13_iVhVaXlP8cpvHvELzmThk7hcRBSAe0whlOAm4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What do you mean by "was found before"?

Comment: and instead of OR matching

Comment: Check my updated answer. I have also added it to your example sheet

Comment: Great!! On iPhone now. Will check later.

Comment: Looks great! Seems to work for test. However - I did set up 3 test cases (see my updated Excel). Test case 1 works, but 2 and 3 are in error N/A. Maybe you would be so kind as to check again.

Comment: Add an IFERROR at beginning, so when there is no match, it will return empty instead of an error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(match(T7&C7&"v",ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(Split(CONCATENATE(T$2:T6&C$2:C6&K$2:K6&"|"),"|"))),0))
```

If this does not work, please give us an example of your data

Comment: That document is private, we cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final formula

`=if(D2<>""; vlookup(arrayformula(MAX(( T$1:T1 = T2 )*4  + ( C$1:C1 = C2 )*2 + ( K$1:K1 = "✓" )*1));Lookup!D:E;2);"")`

- First check if cell empty
- Then find mathcing values above the current    row, start with most
  important first
- Then verify/code-label the    results (7 = full match, 6 = site +
  link, 4 = only site)
- Setup a lookup table to translate the results to values you
  understand